# Autohotkey to select text under cursor?

Tags: autohotkey

Is it possible to select text under cursor using Autohotkey specifically, using a mouse and a key combination. e.g. I specifically want to just do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click on any word in IE/FF/Foxit Reader and a webpage with first Google search result opens up. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it is possible...

The easiest way is to set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+LButton to double click (which selects the current word under the cursor) copy the word to the clipboard and then use google with the parameters `"q="` for the search term and `"btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky"` for using the "I'm Feeling Lucky" function.

It would look like this:

```
^LButton::
Send, {LButton 2}^c
Run, http://www.google.com/search?&q=%clipboard%&btnI=I'm+Feeling+Lucky
return
```

This would work in most cases without issues, the issue comes when selecting words like:

53°C

Jhon's

test%s

and others, because double clicking them only selects the first part of the text before the symbols.

So as long as you are double clicking normal words this should work fine.

Comment: i mentioned in my reply that there would be some issues with that approach... there are other ways of doing this but they are a bit more advanced

Comment: You may also need to add `Sleep 100` after the `Send`.  I noticed that the Copy operation is handled by the OS so it may not have a chance to trigger before the `Run` command in the script.  It will randomly not work and is hard to track.  You can do other things like `WaitClip` but it can get complicated to make it 100% failure proof.

Comment: This would also cause probs if you want to copy the text of a button as double clicking will effectively press the button. Why would you want to copy a button text? Example: Get the odds displayed on Betfair back/place buttons

Comment: @Cristofayre thats a bit trickier because you cannot select text from a button like that, you would have to use `ControlGetText` and pass it the ClassNN of the button to try and get the text. As soon as you are trying to add more "features" to the script you'll find that the code will get more and more complex. :)

Comment: I MIGHT have solved it, (at least on Betfair although not tried yet). I move the mouse to JUST OUTSIDE the blue/pink button region, then use MouseClickDrag to draw a rectangle around the text,  and then copy to clipboard. Doesn't work on a button, but does on Betfair, so can only assume they use a div to put text above the pink/blue buttons.